# User can't access user databases in SQL Server. Can access only system databases

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created new user in SQL Server 2012 on one of my cloud machines. But when I try to access any database other than the system ones, they are not accessible. Showing dialog "*The Database XXX is not accessible*".

How can I access all the tables which are created by other users? OR how can I make user who has all the database object access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using the below steps.

1. Assign a default database for this login

[image: Assign a default user]

2. You can also map multiple database to this user

[image: User Mapping in SQL Server]

Comment: Thanks. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to assign Server / Database role to new sql login
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669065(v=vs.110).aspx